# C++ Access Violation when executing pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, sfml, access-violation

I'm working on a game with c++ and sfml where I have asteroids falling down the screen and the player shoots lasers up to destroy them. When the asteroids or lasers go off of the screen, they are deleted and erased from their respective std::vectors:

asteroids:

```
std::vector<Asteroid*>::iterator it;
for (it = asteroids.begin(); it < asteroids.end(); ) {
    (*it)->update(dt);

    if ((*it)->getPosition().y > Game::window.getSize().y) {
        delete * it;
        asteroids.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        it++;
    }
}
```

lasers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lasers.size(); i++) {
    lasers.at(i)->update(dt);

    if (lasers.at(i)->getPosition().y < 0) {
        delete lasers.at(i);
        lasers.erase(lasers.begin() + i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

The issue comes when I try to detect collisions between them. I loop through all of the asteroids in each instance of laser, and check the collisions between them using a method from a parent class, GameObject.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Game::spawner->asteroids.size() - 1; i++) {

    if (isColliding(asteroids.at(0))) { // Access violation executing location 0x071DE528.
        printf("collided");
        //delete asteroids.at(i);
        //asteroids.erase(asteroids.begin() + i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is the isColliding and getPosition method:

```
bool GameObject::isColliding(GameObject * g) {

sf::Vector2f gPos = g->getPosition();
sf::Vector2f pos = this->getPosition(); // after waiting a few seconds and then testing the collision, I get this error here: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.



if (gPos.x <= pos.x && pos.x <= gPos.x + g->width 
    || pos.x <= gPos.x && gPos.x <= pos.x + width) {

    if (gPos.y <= pos.y && pos.y <= gPos.y + g->height
        || pos.y <= gPos.y && gPos.y <= pos.y + height) {

        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

```
sf::Vector2f GameObject::getPosition() {

if (isLoaded) {
    if (animated)
        return animatedSprite.getPosition();
    else
        return sprite.getPosition(); // the asteroids are not animated, so this will be called.

}
```

}

I've spent a few hours on this and I can't seem to figure out what's happening. I think I'm deleting the pointers and their indexes safely, so I don't know where to go from there. For reference, the isColliding function does work with two distinct GameObjects (player and asteroid). It seems like the issue is somehow related to the looping through all asteroids.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATED Asteroid deletion:

```
int toDelete = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < asteroids.size(); i++) {
    asteroids.at(i)->update(dt);

    if (asteroids.at(i)->getPosition().y > Game::window.getSize().y) {
        toDelete = i;
    }
}

if (toDelete != -1) {
    delete asteroids.at(toDelete);
    asteroids.erase(asteroids.begin() + toDelete);
}
```

Comment: You cant iterate over a vector like that and also call `erase` on it.

Comment: If `asteroids` is empty, then `i < Game::spawner->asteroids.size() - 1` is true!

Answer (score 1):

You are using iterators to go through the asteroids and then delete them, however the documentation states that after calling `erase` the iterators are invalidated:

[Erase documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

> Iterators, pointers and references pointing to position (or first) and beyond are invalidated, with all iterators, pointers and references to elements before position (or first) are guaranteed to keep referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call.

Hence, after the first call to erase your pointers are no longer valid and anything can happen. Try another strategy for deletion, like identify first the doomed asteroids and then erase them separately.

Comment: Could the iterator (or in the case of the laser, the indexed variable) not just be adjusted to account for the erase? For example, i’m only incrementing it when it doesn’t erase an entry. erase() doesn’t change the order entries in the vector, right?

Comment: No, the iterator can't be adjusted to account for the erase, that's not how it works. After you call erase the iterator becomes invalid and there's nothing you can do about it. You can try to work your way around that and you might find a valid position, however that's not how they are supposed to be used, so there's no guaranties about it.

Comment: I am now deleting the asteroids outside of the loop, but the problem persists. Both errors still happen, at seemingly random times. I included the updated code in the original question.

Comment: It's hard to tell just by looking, but an access violation on address 0x00000000 means you are passing a null pointer. I'd suggest you to use smart pointers to handle the allocation/de-allocation.